# Redeem multisig tx using bcoin with multiple inputs (from an exhcnage)

Tags: multi-signature, bcoin

I have a multisig tx with multiple inputs and I'm having trouble completing this tx.

Here's an example tx https://blockchain.com/btc/address/3HMQrFkYexL3FMhPnXPAoDFsFs8LiqB8ou

Following the bcoin guide, I'm stuck at step 2 during the redeem part. https://bcoin.io/guides/multisig-tx.html

The error I get is Code: -25, Error: bad-txns-inputs-missingorspent

How can one redeem a multisig tx with multiple inputs?

Answer (score 1):

That guide might be a bit outdated. There is a newer guide that just runs through the CLI commands [here](https://bcoin.io/guides/multisig-cli.html).

You can also join us on [bcoin slack](https://bcoin.io/slack-signup.html) or on IRC in the #bcoin channel.

We'd need more information from you about how you constructed your transaction. The error you're getting indicates that you are trying to spend from a non-existent output. It may never have existed, or it may have already been spent in the past.

Comment: There was another tx I redeemed that only had one input like from a self hosted wallet and that went through using the guide. I suspect I need to somehow add all the inputs.

Comment: If you redeemed that output already you can't redeem (spend) it a second time. If you have other unspent outputs just create a new transaction that only spends those.